# How to modify an access and modify object across different jsx files in react

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 child components and 1 parent component in React with `.jsx` extentions

In Child 1 I'm setting an object data using `setState`

```
this.setState({data:{someobect}})
```

In Child 2 I want to access this data and modify

In my parent class I have code like this

```
import Child1 from .src/child1.jsx
import Child2 from .src/child2.jsx

<div>

<child1>
<child2>

</div>
```

What is the process of accessing any object between two different children?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to hoist the state up to the parent and have the children delegate to the parent component to receive that information.

```
import Child1 from .src/child1.jsx
import Child2 from .src/child2.jsx


class Parent Extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      data: {}
    }
  }


  _updateData = (newData) => {
    this.setState({
      data: newData
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <child1 data={this.state.data} updateData={this._updateData}>
        <child2 data={this.state.data} >  
      </div>  
    )
  }
}
```

and in your child1 component where you need to update data just called `this.props.updateData` with the new data object you want to update too and then both components will be updated simultaneously and state is managed in one spot.

Answer (score 1):

With `this.setState({data:{someobect}})` You set local state for your component.
If you want to use this object for both children you should set it with props from parent.